# Post a JSON Array into Spring Boot 2 JPA

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to post like this :

```
[{
        "employeeid": "1111",
        "employeename": "YOA"

},
{
        "employeeid": "2222",
        "employeename": "OYA"
}]
```

My controller like this :

```
@PostMapping("/api/employee/save")
public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody List<Employee> employee) {
        return employeeService.save(employee);
}
```

Model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
int id;
@Column(name = "EMP_ID")
int employeeid;
@Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_NAME")
String employeename;

//GETTER AND SETTER
}
```

When i post data,  The error I get is the following:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-13T03:36:25.898+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!",
    "path": "/api/employee/save"
}
```

Service :

```
public interface employeeService{

    Employee save(List<Employee> employee);

}
```

Service Imp :

```
@Service("employeeService")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public Employee save(List<Employee> employee) {
     return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends Repository <Employee, Long>
    Employee save(List<Employee> employee);
}
```

The error description is this:
Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!

when using saveAll(), I Get Error message : No property saveAll found for type Employee

is there anyone who can help me ?
I have modified my question.

Regards,
Me

Comment: Can you show/add how do you save the employees in the `employeeService`?

Comment: @zeagord
public interface employeeService {

 Employee save(List<Employee> employee);

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line

```
public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody List<Employee> employee) {
        return employeeService.save(employee);  //  Problem 
}
```

`employeeService.save` can take only one Object of Entity in your case `Employee`

There are 2 ways

1.

```
public Boolean createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody List<Employee> lstEmployee) {
    try{
        for(Employee emp : lstEmployee){
            employeeService.save(employee);
        }
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return false;
}
```

2.

Use **saveAll** instead

```
public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody List<Employee> employee) {
        return employeeService.saveAll(employee);  
}
```

**Edit 1:**

After adding service class it looks like you are manually implementing so

**Option 1:**

I would suggest you directly use `EmployeeRepository` in your controller class.
As by manually overriding there methods you are not actually 
enjoying benefit of using Repository

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@PostMapping("/api/employee/save")
public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody List<Employee> lstEmployee) {
        return employeeRepository.saveAll(lstEmployee);
}
```

**Option 2:**

Longer way, change your implementation like this. There might be some error for Object but it should give you an idea

```
public interface employeeService{

    Employee save(Employee employee);

    public <S extends User> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entites);



}

@Service("employeeService")
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public Employee save(Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

   @Override
    public List<Employee> saveAll(List<Employee> employee) {
        return employeeRepository.saveAll(employee);
    }

}
```

Comment: when using saveAll(), I Get Error message : No property saveAll found for type Employee

Comment: Can you add employeeService class in Question

Comment: public interface employeeService {

 Employee save(List<Employee> employee);

}

Comment: This is Interface Can you add its Implementation class as well.... Pls modify your question and add there so its more' readable

Comment: I have modified my question.

Comment: I have modified my Answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using spring-data-jpa repository. Let know if it is otherwise. You're trying to use the `save` api which only saves one entity. What you need is `saveAll()` which saves all the given entity. Please read the documentation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-

**Edit: Updated answer to save all records**
The save method will return all the employees so change the type to `List<Employees>`

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends Repository <Employee, Long>
    List<Employee> saveAll(List<Employee> employee);
}
```

Even better use one of the pre-supplied interfaces for simple CRUD operations for example `CrudRepository`. It reduces the boilerplate code that you may have write.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories

```
 public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository <Employee, Long>

    }
```

Comment: Not sure he is... he would get a compile time error not a 500. Cannot save a list if the method requires a single object.

Comment: @zeagord when using saveAll(),
I Get Error message :
No property saveAll found for type Employee